# Getting area of a line circle intersection

Tags: c++, math, 3d

I have a circle and I have two parallel lines which go through straight through it (always 2 intersections).
The radius of the circle is 500, meaning its area is 500 * 500 * pi.

[Quick paint image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edkl5.png) of example above. The red area is the overlapping area, which I want to calculate. However I'm not sure how to, this is what I currently have:

```
const float radius = 500.0f;
float area = (radius * radius) * PI;

Vector3 intersect1, intersect2;  
if (CircleLineIntersection(center, point1, point2, radius, &intersect1, &intersect2) == 2) {
   ...

   float remainingArea = area - ...;
}
```

So how should I proceed to calculate the red area (or both green areas)?

Comment: Can the lines intersect each other?

Comment: @beothunder no. The lines are always parallel.

Comment: If the lines are ALWAYS parallel then there is probably a more efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claculate the green area, subtract it from the area of the circle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: I would if I knew how to, I can get the angle between (point1 - center) and (point2 - center), but not sure where to go from there. `the red area (or *both green areas*)`.

Edit: didn't see the link, thank you!